# how to create url with function yii2

Tags: php, url, yii, yii2, base-url

I want to get base URL with parameter in ***Yii2***
eg

```
functionName("controller/action");
```

I want

```
domain.com/controller/action
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is  use the proper yii helpers for ruoting .. in this the `yii\helpers\Url;`

eg:

```
 Url::to(['controller/action'], true);
```

see yii2 doc this https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing